# Forty poor thieves

Tags: combinatorics

Forty thieves have 4000 gold coins to split between them. A group of five thieves is $poor$ if together they have less than or equal to 500 gold coins. Let N be the minimum number of poor groups of five thieves among all groups of five thieves. Find N. I know the answer can be calculated using Subtraction rule(total groups-the groups which do not satisfy the equation). But how do I apply it?

Comment: Here's a hint: start with the equal distribution where they all get 100 coins.  Then all groups of 5 are poor.  So if you want to minimize the number of poor groups, you want many thieves to have at least 501 coins.  Try a few different mild redistributions of the coins from the equal distribution and look at what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we give $101$ coins to each of $39$ thieves; that’s $3939$ coins altogether, so Leifr hinn óheppni<sup>1</sup>, the $40$-th thief, gets only $61$ coins. Let $F$ be a group of five thieves.

- Is $F$ poor if Leifr is in $F$?
- What if Leifr is not in $F$?
- How many poor groups of five thieves are there if we use this distribution of coins?

A harder question is whether we can do any better than this.

<sup>1</sup> Leif the Unlucky

Comment: We can actually let Leifr - or Dopey - keep $65$ coins. If $4$ other thieves still have only $100$ coins each, it doesn't change which groups are poor. But since it doesn't change the number, it's effectively the same solution.

Answer (score -1):

You have two problems: Calculate the number of poor groups given a particular coin distribution - relatively straightforward - and find (and prove) the best coin distribution.

The first thought - after checking that an equal distribution will, in fact, mean all groups are poor - is to plunder one thief's wealth by distributing an extra coin from his hoard to each of the other thieves. Let's call that thief Dopey. Then only groups containing Dopey are poor - a total  of ${{39}\choose{4}}$ groups. The challenge then is to find out whether this is in fact the best solution.